# Highchart/Chart.js/FusionChart: column range customized chart

Tags: angular, highcharts, chart.js, fusioncharts, canvasjs

Regards to all Stackoverflow members, I'm trying to build a chart using Highcharts which has a customized behavior as shown/attached as an image.

I'm trying to achieve this with a Columnrange type and attached the inprogress fiddle for the same at the link: [Highchart-columnrange-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58xgpd1L/3/),
and I think data inputs should look something like below for achieving attached highchart expectation:

`series: [{
        name: 'Temperatures',
        data: [
            ['Black', 88, 60],
            ['Blue', 22 - 58, 60],
            ["Yellow", 32, (-22) - 154],
            ['Orange', -18, 60],
            ["Green", 54, (-22) - 154],
            ["Gray", , 121 - 143, 60]
        ]
    }]`

[image: Customized Column range chart expected]

Could someone suggest if this kind of highchart can be achieved via highcharts? in which based on the inputs there would be below category of line.

- Horizontal lines from start of index on Y-Axis till the end of X-Axis width(60) in this case
- Vertical lines from start of index on X-Axis till the end of Y-Axis(200) for instance.
- Range from min(20) to max(50) on Y-Axis spans till the end of X-Axis width(60) with background color.

Please do advise if this can be achieved with any of Highcharts/Chart.js/Fusioncharts etc.

Thanks in Advance and your help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Yes, this chart can be built using highcharts, however, it requires a bit of custom code. Have you considered using x-range series type instead of column range?

Comment: Nope, I didn't try x-range series type yet.. could you please share a sample fiddle to get the expected highchart?

Comment: @Chmiel, I've tried with x-series as available in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6mae35x8/1/ and i think it is not suitable for my requirement. Please suggest if any other alternatives.

Comment: You can try with a line series and add lineWidth where you've got rectangles. However, it will require a bit of custom code. Another idea is to use bar series and line series in one chart. Unfortunately, Highcharts doesn't provide such a chart type to achieve it easily.

Comment: It's surprising that huge libraries like Highcharts, CanvasJS, Chart.js, FusionCharts doesn't support this requirement